# Hadoop - Explicit grouping of Mapper result

Tags: java, hadoop, grouping

I have written the mapper code in which the key is emitted as IntTextPair, I want to group the mapper result by just Int from the IntTextPair, like

```
[1   Shanghai]
[1   Test]
[2   Set]
```

and the mapper result should be grouped as:

```
[1   Shanghai, Test]
[2   Set]
```

I have implemented the Comparator class:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator;


public class GroupByInput extends WritableComparator {

    public GroupByInput() {
        super(IntTextPair.class, true);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable it1, WritableComparable it2) {
        IntTextPair Pair1 = (IntTextPair) it1;
        IntTextPair Pair2 = (IntTextPair) it2;

        return Pair1.getFirst().compareTo(Pair2.getFirst());
    }
}
```

and in the configuration file I have set comparator class like this:

```
   Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf);
   job.setGroupingComparatorClass(GroupByInput.class);
```

Am I going to the right direction? I need some assistance

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge/consolidate the key's as you currently outlined. What's the current Mapper output value type/class - is there a reason why you can't output an  KV from the mapper?

If you do have another class / type currently being output from the mapper as the Value component, then you can still somewhat achieve this by:

1. Your GroupComparator looks good, paired with the ordering of IntTextPair means that all keys with the same Int component will be sent to the same reducer.
2. In your reducer, as you iterate the values you can examine the Key to determine the unique list of Text components of the key.

   - it's not very well known that as you iterate the values in the reducer, the contents of the key are updated too - with your grouper the Int component will always be the same for a particular reduce run, but the Text component can change
   - As the keys are ordered, you can keep track of the previous Text component value (be sure to COPY the contents before you iterate to the next value in the values iterable)